# Loading new scene in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scene

I am attempting to switch scenes from a login screen to the main screen of my program but whenever I try to switch scenes after clicking login, I get the following error.

"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

I've messed around with my code and try to change some things to get different results but no dice. This is my first time doing a GUI so any help would be appreciated.

```
package pwmanager;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
*
* @author 176878
*/
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button loginButton;


@FXML
Stage prevStage;
Stage currentStage;
public void setPrevStage(Stage stage){
    this.prevStage = stage;

   }

@FXML
public void getPrevStage(Stage stage){
    this.currentStage = prevStage;
}

@FXML
public void loginButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
   System.out.println("You clicked me, logging in!");
    setPrevStage(prevStage);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    try{ 
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));

    GridPane mainScreen = (GridPane) loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainScreen);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Password Manager");
    stage.show();
    prevStage.hide();
      }

    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Did not load right");
    }

         }

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

}
```

Comment: Please show what the actual cause of the exception is (post the full stack trace if necessary), and identify the line at which it occurs.

Comment: The error is occuring at line 57

Comment: So which line is line 57?

Comment: AnchorPane mainScreen = (AnchorPane) loader.load();  ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.VBox cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane

Comment: Well, I don't see that line in the code you posted. But if it's a class cast exception then you are trying to cast to the wrong type (i.e. your FXMLLoader is not creating an `AnchorPane`).

Comment: Thanks for at least talking me through this. I figured out the issue with this part but now I'm on to my next problem which I'll attempt to workout on my own before asking for help. Thanks for the support

Comment: Please consider contributing to the community by updating your question with the solution you found...